# Loading every different user own data

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I am making an app that the user could add many accounts and view it in the `UITableView`  and I am holding the name via `NSUserDefaults` and once the name is clicked in the `UITableView` it will open a different page that has many data fields to fill which is DONE.

For example when the user click on John or other name. The user could see his own data. My problem is that how could I show for every user his own data? Also could I make this via `NSUserDefaults` ?

It smiler to contacts tab in the iPhone. I hope I could explain my problem.

My source code I hope it helps [Download Link](http://dropbox.com/s/41yxlr50jnovnl0/SavaDataIm-2.zip)

Comment: Are you saying that a single user uses the app and stores data about multiple accounts that all belong to the one user or is this a table of data about many different users?

Comment: @DirectX It is a table of data about many different users that entered by the user itself. Thanks

Comment: I also assume a user is supposed to only see their own data?  NSuserdefaults is good for small data like preferences.  It could work for this if each users looks at their own data only.  Using coredata etc may be better for you or at least using some kind of file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer hasn't common answer without knowing your architecture and data which you show in table. Generally database greatly solve this problem - you store all data in db and fetch by predicate only needed data -

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name== %@", userName];
NSArray *orders = [Order findAllUsingPredicate:predicate]; // this is prototype method
```

But database is being used for large amount of data, and if you don't want to use db or have static data to display then look at [plists](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i). You can create plist with nodes

```
-John
  -Order1,Order2
-Mike
  -Order3,Order4,Order5
...
```

Then read this file, and fetch John's object like this:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:pathToPlist];
johnsObjects = [dict objectForKey:@"John"];
```

Hope, it will be helpful for you

Comment: Thanks beryllium. I have added the source code if you want to see my architecture. https://www.dropbox.com/s/41yxlr50jnovnl0/SavaDataIm-2.zip

Answer (score 0):

Use a document-based app (`UIDocument`). Give each user his own document. Switch between documents when you switch users. See [Document-Based App Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Thanks Rob, I have added my source code I hope it helps on what I need.